# How to get lat lng with 6m accuracy on polyline draw between 2 points 1Km apart using google maps

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, maps

I have a polyline drawn on a map between two points which are 1 KM apart. I want to get the lat long on the polyline with 6m accuracy ie lat long of points on the polyline which are 6 m apart. How can we do this?

Here is the code to used to draw the polyline

```js
// google maps showing polylines between two points

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 26.138434, lng: 75.783714},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 26.138434, lng: 75.783714},
    {lat: 26.091578, lng: 75.830330}
   
    
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for 1000 meters you can assum  the surface as  plain (as   a geometry) and based on this you could simply use a proportion between difference of lat and lng then loop for build all the coords you need  adding the related  step

```
  dlat = 26.138434 - 26.091578;
  dlng = 75.830330 - 75.783714;

  addLat = (6*dlat)/1000;
  addLng = (6*dlng)/1000;

  i = 0;
  l = 0;
  while ( l <1000)  {

    myLat[i] = 26.091578 + addLat*i;
    myLng[i] = 26.091578 + addLng*i;
    i++;
    l = l+6;
  }
```